# Calling a Restful webservice from oracle pl/sql

Tags: web-services, rest, plsql

I am calling a **restful** API from **pl/sql**. the restful api is using http not https  but it gives me the following error-

```
**ORA-29266: end-of-body reached**. I have write the following code---

   DECLARE
      lo_req            UTL_HTTP.req;
      lo_resp           UTL_HTTP.resp;
      HTTP_REQ          UTL_HTTP.REQ;
      HTTP_RESP         UTL_HTTP.RESP;
      t_http_resp       UTL_HTTP.resp;
      l_response_text   CLOB;
      v_url             VARCHAR2 (1024);
      pAllparameter     VARCHAR2 (1024);
      vSms              VARCHAR2(1024):='Hellow How Are Yoy';
   BEGIN
      UTL_HTTP.set_detailed_excp_support (TRUE);
      lo_req :=
         UTL_HTTP.
          begin_request ('URL'
            || 'smsText='
            || vSms
            || '&mobileNo='
            || pMobileNo,
            'POST',
            UTL_HTTP.HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
      lo_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response (lo_req);
    UTL_HTTP.read_text (lo_resp, l_response_text);
      -- A successfull request would have the status code "200".
    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_response_text);
  UTL_HTTP.end_response (lo_resp);
    --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (pAllparameter);
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
        UTL_HTTP.end_response (lo_resp);
         RAISE;
   END;
```

WHEN I Invoke the Procedure It Gives Me Error.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

It will always raise the exception `ORA-29266: end-of-body` whenever it reaches the end of HTTP response if `detailed_exception` is enabled. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#CHDCDCAB).

I usally loop through the response body (just in case it is longer than expected), then I catch this exception explicitly even if I do not do anything, apart from loggin the body has ended

```
   DECLARE
      lo_req            UTL_HTTP.req;
      lo_resp           UTL_HTTP.resp;
      HTTP_REQ          UTL_HTTP.REQ;
      HTTP_RESP         UTL_HTTP.RESP;
      t_http_resp       UTL_HTTP.resp;
      l_response_text   CLOB;
      v_url             VARCHAR2 (1024);
      pAllparameter     VARCHAR2 (1024);
      vSms              VARCHAR2(1024):='Hellow How Are Yoy';
      buffer            VARCHAR2(4000);
   BEGIN
      UTL_HTTP.set_detailed_excp_support (TRUE);
      lo_req :=
         UTL_HTTP.
          begin_request ('URL'
            || 'smsText='
            || vSms
            || '&mobileNo='
            || pMobileNo,
            'POST',
            UTL_HTTP.HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
      lo_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response (lo_req);
    BEGIN
      LOOP
        utl_http.read_line(lo_resp, buffer);
        l_response_text := l_response_text || buffer;
      END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
      utl_http.end_response(res);
    END;
  END;
```